# Update Large Dataset without hanging the browser with EmberSJ

Tags: ember.js

I'm using EmberJS to present a table to the user. I currently test it with about 60 rows and 25 columns and the result are not so great.
The data is a list of people with 24 metrics on them, the user can check and uncheck several checkboxes to change the metrics.
I use ArrayController bound to the 60 rows and I update them when any checkbox is changing, the ArrayController has the sortProperties set to choose by which column to sort the table.

1. When the change does not cause a reorder of the rows it takes about 2-3 seconds to update the whole table.
2. When the change cause a reorder to the rows it may take up-to 4 seconds.

Is there a way to make the update more smooth? even if it will only look smoother while the update still take 3 seconds?

I use Ember.beginPropertyChanges and endPropertyChanges.

Ido

Comment: what version of ember do you use ? this commit https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/4aecc4226caf9c352cb983472b91991743018225 may have improved this. Let me know if it works better.

Comment: I'm still on pre-1.0 because when I update to the latest version the handlesbar templates were append to the end of the body instead of where they where define. How can I update to the latest version, the EmberJS website still point to pre-1.0

Comment: The website currently point to 1.0-pre2 which includes the commit I pointed. Would it be possible to isolate the table part of your app, and post a link to a jsfiddle or jsbin ? you can find the up-to-date starting point here: http://emberjs.com/community/

Comment: Thank you, I'll update and check it again. I've post another question with few samples but it pretty long question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the latest version this improve sorting performance.